# Fastboot in Samsung note 3 sm-n9005 (lte), does it exist?

Tags: fastboot

I'm trying to root and mod an old note 3, with a lot of effort because there are no more guides, links, etc.

I start from a stock rom lolipop (just installed).

Among the first things to do it seems there is oem unlocking, which some lucky ones have in the developer options, but I don't.

Unblocking oem seems to have to be done with adb, fastboot with a couple of commands:

```
adb reboot bootloader
fastboot oem unlock
```

The first one (adb) works (the phone restarts in download mode)
The second waits for the device... forever...

(fastboot devices is always empty)

I have read many guides and tutorials about it, reinstalled all drivers, adb, android tools, sdk, etc, etc, etc.

I tried in 4 different pc, 2 with win 7 and two with linux, I tried in a thousand different ways, with different software, different kies, etc, etc, etc.

By now I'm exasperated this thing never works... and I'm starting to think that maybe it doesn't exist...

Is there fastboot in note 3 sm-n9005 (lte)? Is there oem block? This thing should work? Is it really necessary for rooting, modding, etc?

*I keep insisting and trying to make it work because in the meantime I have gone even further... I rooted with cf-auto-root, installed twrp, lineageos, etc, but there is always something wrong... the root loses it by installing a custom (lineage is not rooted), twrp I can only install version 2.8 or a modified 3.3.1 version, I can install lineageos (also 17) but not other mods like paranoid (everything is fine, but at end of install an infinite loop), there is actually something wrong, and the only thing I couldn't get to work is this damn fastboot... so I think it's him, but maybe not?*

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very simple way to root and install a custom ROM on all older Galaxy phones.

1. Put the phone into download mode
2. Get the Samsung software (I forgot what it was called) but it allows you to flash recoveries. Look on the web for the exact name.
3. Find TWRP for your phone and flash it using the software (there is a specific setting you must flash in but you can look on the web for that)
4. Get your ROM (it can be anything).
5. Flash SuperSU or that other new root manager (Magisk)
6. Get you GAPPs as well.

You're done!